# Framework agnostic custom element with v-model doesn't work

Tags: vue.js

I am facing an issue.
I am currently working on a framework agnostic element library with the new browser API `customElements.define()` and created a custom input and would like him to work with v-model binding.

But, it does not work. I am able to bind a value with `:value="prop"` but v-model simply does not work.

```js
class LmTag extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.template = document.querySelector("#lmTag");
    this.shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
    this.clone = document.importNode(this.template.content, true);
    this.shadow.appendChild(this.clone);
    this.input = this.shadow.querySelector('input');
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.value = this.getAttribute("value");
  }
  
  get value() {
    return this.input.value;
  }
  
  set value(value) {
    this.input.value = value;
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log(attr, oldValue, newValue);
  }
}

customElements.define("lm-tag",  LmTag);

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lights: true,
    input: "model"
  },
  methods: {
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template id="lmTag">
  <style>
    .lm-tag {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #e74c3c;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    .lm-tag input {
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
  <span class="lm-tag">
    <input type="text"/>
    <content></content>
  </span>
</template>
<div id="app" class="text-center body">
  <p>
    Binding :value
    <lm-tag :value="input">{{input}}</lm-tag>
  </p>
  <p>
    Binding v-model
    <lm-tag v-model="input">{{input}}</lm-tag>
  </p>
  <p>
    Raw input with :value
    <input type="text" :value="input">
  </p>
  <p>
    Raw input with v-model
    <input type="text" v-model="input">
  </p>
</div>
```

Could you help a fellow dev having trouble with his code?

Thank you!

Comment: please always provide the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Already provided, look at the codepen.

Comment: not in the codepen or any external tool but in the question itself.

Comment: My bad, I added it to the post

Comment: someone will help, i'm not able  to understand your issue.